# Tkinter - Update changes in variables in previously generated widgets, from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, widget

I need to represent in "ventana2" the pairs entered in "ventana", so that a new frame appears when the key is new. When the key already exists in the dictionary, I need to change the old value in the frame created for that key previously (the new value is adding old and new).
I can not get the frames permanently related to my dictionary partner, through the key.
Thank you very much in advance, and sorry for my english.
Here is a summary of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana2 = tk.Tk()

name = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=name, width=30).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(ventana, text = 'Nombre').grid(row=0, column=0)

value = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=value, width=30).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Label(ventana, text = 'Celular').grid(row=1, column=0)

contactos={}

def intro():
    nom = name.get()
    if nom in contactos:
        cel = contactos[nom] + float(value.get())
        contactos[nom] = cel
    else:
        cel = float(value.get())
        contactos[nom] = cel
        create_widget()

def create_widget():
    frame = tk.Frame(ventana2)
    frame.pack()
    nomb = tk.Label(frame, text=name.get()).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    telf = tk.Label(frame, text=contactos[name.get()]).pack(side=tk.RIGHT) 


intro_btn = tk.Button(ventana, text='Intro', command = intro)
intro_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'ew')

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Never ever create multiple `Tk` instances at the same time.

Comment: In my true code, it is not like that. Here I did it just to represent it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Labels created inside the `create_widget()` function is in the function scope. After the function ends all references to the label is lost. So you need to think of a way to save references to the label (suggest return statement) and associate them to the dictionary of contactos.

**Update - relate a frame with a value**

Save a reference to the object you wish to remember and the name you want to use to recall it in a list(or dict or tuple et.). Then append all that to your global list of widgets. For example:

```
nomb = tk.Label( ... )
widget_parameters = ['Nomb Label', nomb]
global_widget_list.append(widget_parameters)
```

Then you can search the `global_widget_list` for any widget you have named and get a referance to that widget.

I have included some example code to illustrate one way that you can accomplish that. Play around with it until you understand it and you will be able to implement it in your own application.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

global_widget_list = []    # List for holding all widgets

def make_label():   # Create label
    text_label = Label(root,text='Text input')
    text_label.pack()
    global_widget_list.append(['Text Label',text_label]) # Add widget to list

def make_input():   # Create entry
    inputvar = StringVar()
    text_input = Entry(root,width=20,textvariable=inputvar)
    text_input.pack()
    global_widget_list.append(['Text Input',text_input,inputvar]) # Add widget to list

make_label()    # Run functions to cretae GUI
make_input()
root.update()   # Take care of updating GUI
time.sleep(3)   # Wait so you have time to see the original, then change it

# Now, loop through all widgets and do what you want
for widget in global_widget_list:
    widget_name = widget[0]
    widget_id = widget[1]
    print(widget_name, 'has identity', widget_id)

    if widget_name == 'Text Label':
        print('Changing test label text to: ALL CAPS')
        widget_id.configure(text='ALL CAPS')

    if widget_name == 'Text Input':
        print('Changing text in entry to: SAMPLE')
        var = widget[2]
        var.set('SAMPLE')

root.update()   # Take care of updating GUI
time.sleep(3)   # Wait so you have time to see the changes, then change it

print('Removing Entry from application GUI')
global_widget_list[1][1].pack_forget() # Remove entry form GUI
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to relate a frame with a value? How would you do it?

Comment: Great! Thanks! But python crashes when I try to run it... Do you know why it could happen?

Comment: Are you running the exact code in my example? Do you get any error messages? Else you can try to find the problem by starting with just the import statements and adding the rest of the program piece by piece and see when it crashes. That will give you a point to start debugging